# Stomp frame clear - Flutter

Tags: flutter, notifications, flutter-dependencies, stomp

We are using `stomp_dart_client` a third-party library in our project. It is used to send/receive notifications in our Application. We are using the notification to print the `kot` in our Windows application. The problem we are facing is the frame is keep on adding `kot` and printing duplicate kot's each time. We need to clear the stomp frame each time we receive the notification. Please guide us on how to clear the stomp frame to resolve the issue.

We tried to activate and deactivate the stomp client still the issue persists.